# What is the number of ways to put n distinct balls into n+1 boxes, n of which are identical and the other of which is different?

Tags: combinatorics, bell-numbers

What is the number of ways to put n distinct balls into n+1 boxes, n of which are identical and the other of which is different (say, it is larger than the rest)?

I understand that this is a question regarding Bell numbers, but I am unsure how to include the box that is different in this. 
I have that there are n+1 ways to pick this box, and n+1 ways to pick the empty box, and the number of ways to partition [n] is B(n). So the total would be $B(n)(n+1)^2$

Comment: There may be more than one empty box.

Comment: Yes, I believe so, but wouldn't the partitions of [n] account for this?

Comment: The Bell numbers are for putting identical balls into identical boxes.  You don't have to choose the special box, it is chosen for you.  You just choose which balls go into it.

Comment: There are ${n\choose k}$ ways to choose the balls that go into the distinguished box for $k=0,1,\dots,n.$  Then we put $n-k$ distinct balls into $n$ identical boxes.

Answer (score 1):

There are ${n\choose k}$ ways to choose the balls that go into the distinguished box for $k=0,1\dots,n.$ Then we put $n-k$ distinct balls into $n$ identical boxes, so we have $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}P(n-k, n)$$ ways where $P(n,n-k)$ is the number of ways to put $n-k$ distinct objects into $n$ identical boxes.  Since we don't care which boxes we use, this is simply the number of ways to partition a set of $n-k$ objects, or to put it another way, the number of equivalence classes on a set of $n-k$ objects.  That is, $P(n-k,n)$ is just $B(n-k)$, the Bell number.  The final answer is $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}B(n-k)$$